# How to get RackSpace servers with a certain tag?

Tags: python, openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace, pyrax

Trying to fetch all the servers registered to our RackSpace account under a certain tag.

Using RackSpace's Python bindings for OpenStack, [`pyrax`](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/docs/pyrax_doc.md), we haven't found a way to do this.  Is there some way to achieve it with that library, or is there another Python library that would do that?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Just as a complement: you can also use nova to access the API (http://developer.rackspace.com/blog/getting-started-using-python-novaclient-to-manage-cloud-servers.html), but anyway, if the API does not have tags information, it won't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the author of `pyrax`. Currently there is no way to access tag information via pyrax, as that information is not returned from the API. But I agree that that would be useful information, so I'm talking to the various teams involved to see what might be possible. When I hear something I'll follow up here.

Comment: Excellent!  Much better answer than I expected.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I would be interested if you have any new information on this? adding a new server with tags in the control panel doesn't appear to populate the metadata within the api at time of writing still.

Comment: As of this posting, Rackspace still has not added tag support to the API. There is a UserVoice request for that feature here: https://feedback.rackspace.com/forums/71021-product-feedback/suggestions/5709402-expose-cloud-server-tags-through-the-api

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the metadata for cloud servers is currently available, which appears to contain the labels of the server.

You could list servers using pxrax and filter on the metadata.